# Rails ActiveRecord: two has_one relationships between the same models

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord

I have a model, Project, that has 2 associations to the same model:

```
belongs_to :source_connection, class: Connection
belongs_to :destination_connection, class: Connection
```

That works fine - I can access connection methods through project without any issues.

I'm a little confused on how to do the inverse, however. I started with a rather optimistic:

```
has_one :project
```

on the Connection model, and unsurprisingly, it throws an

`ActiveModel::MissingAttributeError: can't write unknown attribute 'connection_id'`

error when I try to access the project from the connection itself.

If anyone knows how I can declare the association on the connection side, I'd be appreciative. Cheers.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**Associations**

You will probably be best looking at the [`foreign_key`](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/association_basics.html#self-joins) arguments for ActiveRecord Associations:

```
#app/models/project.rb
Class Project < ActiveRecord::Base
   belongs_to :source_connection, class: "Connection", foreign_key: "source_connection_id"
   belongs_to :destination_connection, class: "Connection", foreign_key: "destination_connection_id"
end

#app/models/connection.rb
Class Connection < ActiveRecord::Base
   has_many :projects, foreign_key: "source_connection_id"
end
```

The issue you have is that since you're not using the `foreign_key` option in your associations, Rails will be looking for the standard `foreign_key` associations inside your schema (typically `model_name_id`).

--

**Error**

> can't write unknown attribute 'connection_id'

I don't know why it's complaining about *writing*, but the reason is likely that you don't have the correct foreign key set up for your association. Typically, Rails will be looking for the `model_name_id` - but since you're not, you'll need to set the relative key in your models (as demonstrated)

Comment: If he's using build or create from his connection class it'd be complaining about writing I assume?

Comment: Probably! The OP didn't mention how he was calling the class, so I just wanted to give my opinion on it

Answer (score 3):

```
has_one :project, foreign_key: 'source_connection_id'
```

Rails is looking for connection_id as the error says, as you've used source_connection and destination_connection you need to tell it to use the correct foreign key to look it up.

You might want to define them as:

```
has_one :source_project, foreign_key: 'source_connection_id'
has_one :destination_project, foreign_key: 'destination_connection_id'
```

Because you won't be able to call them both project.